# Open form in subfolder

Tags: c#, forms

Ok,  new to C# (What a pain!!!) and I am simply trying to have a button on Form1 open Form2

My structure:

Root Folder
     |
     Screens
          |
          Form1.cs
          Form2.cs

My Code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Visible = false;
        MessageBox.Show("pausing for 3 sec");

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);


        Screens.Form2 f2 = new WindowsFormsApp1.Screens.Form2();
        f2.ShowDialog;
    }
```

The error is on the f2.showdialog; line:

> Error: CS0201  C# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

This makes no sense.  I believe I am properly calling the form in the subfolder?

Comment: ShowDialog is a method, so it should be f2.ShowDialog()

Comment: Try to use it as a function: `f2.ShowDialog();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f2.ShowDialog;` isn't a method call (because there are no brackets `()`), so the compiler thinks you're trying to execute a property or field.

It should be `f2.ShowDialog();`

Comment: OK,  I don't understand how you guys run your forums here but this is not an offtopic discussion...

Secondly, Why remove the language I was programming in the title?  It helps other users identify which language I was using.

Comment: @stackoverflow_user It's seen as off topic because it's effectively a simple typo (and therefore not that useful to future readers). As for removing the language from the title, it's because the [tagging help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) explicitly states you shouldn't do it (see "Should I use tags in titles?"). The reason is that most people subscribe to tags that they are interested in. I found your question by looking at the C# tag, not searching for C#. In short: the tagging system is more than sufficient. Good luck with learning C# and welcome to StackOverflow :-)

Comment: Funny, I would imagine a lot of users new to a language would have a  lot of typo issues as they learn the structure. C# / C++ and numerous other languages are very grammatically strict.  I would think people like me who come from a VB world find it difficult to understand all the rules in the beginning.

Comment: @stackoverflow_user As someone who came from VB too, I can understand what you mean :) I wouldn't dwell on it too much.